# Trying to move image with UILabel based on text length, constraints do not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, autolayout

I'm trying to have image align with text label, like so:

[image]

To do this I use constraints. I bind the arrow to the right edge, label right side to arrow, and image right side to label left side. Here is the code:

```
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.disclosureIndicator attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:1.0 constant:-15.0]];

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.purposeLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.disclosureIndicator
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0 constant:-10.0]];

NSLayoutConstraint *imgConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.purposeImage attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.purposeLabel
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0 constant:-4.0];
[self.view addConstraint:imgConstraint];
```

But when I try to reduce label text length and sizeToFit, it doesn't work, that can be seen from frames:
[image]

If I reduce `imgConstraint`priority to less then 250 the sizeToFit actually works, label frame changes, but the image does not move at all.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Three constraints you have in your code is not enough to define all sizes for all elements you have. Please post all constraints code. I also suggest to check visual constraint language - it will be much simpler and cleaner then manually creating individual ones. - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage/VisualFormatLanguage.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to remove the autoresizing constraints, like so:

```
self.purposeImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

when I did this, everything worked.